# Gulp Error: "The following tasks did not complete; Did you forget to signal async completion"

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sass, gulp

I tried running `gulp` command on my terminal in the project directory where I have the `gulpfile.js` but I get the error, `The following tasks did not complete: default, gulpSass; Did you forget to signal async completion` which I tried looking for a solution to but to no avail.

I checked out some possible reasons to why I am facing the problem and implemented some but I still kept getting the error.

One of the possible fix I tried was using `async await` in all of the functions but it didn't solve the issue.

This is my **gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp     = require('gulp'),
sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
notify       = require('gulp-notify'),
livereload   = require('gulp-livereload')
concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),


// Concat all js into one script
async function js ( cb ) {
  return await gulp.src(['./assets/js/lib/*.js','./assets/js/scripts/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
    //.pipe(jshint())
    //.pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify()) 
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
    .pipe(livereload());

  cb();
}

// Sass compiler + Maps
async function sass ( cb ) {
  return await gulp.src('./assets/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
    .pipe(sassGlob())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'development'}))
    //.pipe(autoprefixer({
     // browsers: ['>1%'],
    //remove: false
    //}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./assets/maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
    .pipe(livereload());

  cb();
}

// Watch for changes
async function watch ( cb ) {
  livereload.listen();
  return await gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*', ['sass']);
  return await gulp.watch('./assets/js/lib/**/*.js', ['js']);
  return await gulp.watch('./assets/js/scripts/**/*.js', ['js']);
  return await gulp.watch('./**/*.php').on('change', async function(file) {
    livereload.changed(file.path);
  });

  cb();
}

// Error handling/reporting
var plumberErrorHandler = { 
  errorHandler: notify.onError({
    title: 'Gulp',
    message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>'
  })
}

// Default
exports.default = gulp.series(js, sass, watch);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your error message says `The following tasks did not complete: default, gulpSass;` but there is no `gulpSass` task in your code so you changed something before you copied it here.

Second, this syntax is old:

`return await gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*', ['sass']);`

Use this instead:

`gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*', sass);`

You are using the function name form of tasks not the `gulp.task('sass')` syntax, so in the watch calls you use the function name `sass` but not as a string`'sass'`.

Make this change throughout your `watch` task.

And I would get rid of the `return await` - it is probably a problem.